# Error: Chartboost app ID and app signature must be set in the Android manifest

Tags: android, air, chartboost, ane

i have issue and not understand why this error appear after building app using ANE and instructions from this rep.

https://github.com/ChartBoost/air
https://github.com/ChartBoost/air/blob/master/README.md

Chartboost AIR Plugin(3517): Your Chartboost app ID and app signature must be set in the Android manifest (using the AIR application descriptor file's tag). See the AIR plugin documentation for more details.

App ID and it value have been added in this format according to instruction and appears in manifest file:

meta-data android:name="__ChartboostAir__AppID" android:value="5373..." />
meta-data android:name="__ChartboostAir__AppSignature" android:value="4fc5d0..." />

But ANE doesn't recognise them.
Can you advice something?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented Chartboost ANE and my application descriptor file looks like this :

```
<android>
    <colorDepth>16bit</colorDepth>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">


            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



            <!-- This permission is required by Chartboost -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


            <!--This permission is required by Chartboost -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

            <application>
              <!-- The app ID and signature for the Android version of your AIR app must be placed here. -->
              <meta-data android:name="__ChartboostAir__AppID" android:value="5***" />
              <meta-data android:name="__ChartboostAir__AppSignature" android:value="c*****" />

              <!-- Also required for the Chartboost SDK. -->
              <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
            </application>
        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>

<extensions>
    <extensionID>com.chartboost.plugin.air</extensionID>
</extensions>
```

However , it will be better if you may post snippet of your application descriptor file or post a link of it, so that we may be in a better position to understand your problem.